# Webapp2 Python set_cookie does not support samesite cookie?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, webapp2, webob

In [webapp2 documentation](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/response.html#setting-cookies) there is no mention of setting the `SameSite` attribute for a cookie, it seems to be built on the response handler from WebOB, I checked webOB doc page it clearly shows the ['SameSite' flag as an accepted cookie parameter](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/api/cookies.html)

I tried to set it nonetheless in set cookie:

```
self.response.set_cookie(name, secure_cookie, path='/', secure=True,
httponly=True, samesite='lax', expires=expireDate)
```

But I received the below error:

`TypeError: set_cookie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samesite'`

I know one can use `self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', ...` but I was hoping I could use `self.response.set_cookie` following the webapp2 documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Samesite` was introduced in [webob 1.8](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/whatsnew-1.8.html?highlight=samesite#experimental-features) but The App Engine Standard Environment SDK ships with [1.1.1 and 1.2.3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) as built-in libraries.

You could try [vendoring](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) in a more recent `webob` to see if this overrides the built-in version.

Once a version of `webob` that supports `samesite` is installed, a `samesite` keyword argument can be passed to `Response.set_cookie`

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.set_cookie('cookie-name', value='42', samesite='lax')
```

This sample app sets `samesite=strict` on the session cookie generated by `webapp2_extras.sessions`, assuming the underlying webob package supports it.

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions


class HelloHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        try:
            super(HelloHandler, self).dispatch()
        finally:
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        return self.session_store.get_session()

    def get(self):
        self.session['hello'] = 'world'
        self.response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello world')


webapp2_config = { 
    'webapp2_extras.sessions': {
        'secret_key': 's3cr3t',
        'cookie_args':{'samesite': 'strict'}
    },  
}

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=HelloHandler),
],
    config=webapp2_config)
```

The response's `set-cookie` header is

```
session=eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIn0=|1595151290|09b22484901689e6eb0411792c8732ef134d2b66; Path=/; SameSite=strict
```

Comment: That's sad :(! I don't think it's worth importing an underlying library for a missing flag, sounds like something GAE should have done, but I guess with their future plans to move to Python3 and the availability of other frameworks like Flask & Django they might stop upgrading webapp2 and its libraries. Thank you for the heads up! I will go with the add_header approach then..

Comment: @Khaled Please can you elaborate the add_header approach? How would you set the SameSite attribute on the cookie?

Comment: if your project in running in django version>2.1 this will be fixed automatically if the version is not you have to implement that and had to set the headers using the middleware.[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite)

Comment: @snakecharmerb any suggestions on how to make webapp2 use newer version of webob? I tired just importing it from vendor libs but no luck. I'm using webapp2.extras sessions, which uses set_cookie, so the workaround using add_header is quite tricky to get right.

Comment: @RobCurtis Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: @snakecharmerb currently python2, haven't done that upgrade yet for gae.

Comment: @RobCurtis I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for this. The issue I have now is that webob doesn't support that (because it's the old version). So I assume I need to vendor in new version of webapp2 with latest webob?

Comment: I ran the example with webapp2 v2.5.2 in app.yaml.libraries and with the latest webob vendored in. (there's no need to specify webob in app.yaml in this case)

Comment: @Yahya - I added this type of solution here

Comment: @Yahya I know it's late but there's an add header function
`self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', '<cookie data>')`
where you can set the `samesite` attribute

Answer (score 1):

I cracked this issue with header change, without install any external library. just use this function after set a cookie:

```
def AddSameSiteToCookies(self):
    for index, header in enumerate(self.response.headers._items):
        if header[0] == "Set-Cookie" and "SameSite" not in header[1]:
            temp = list(header)
            temp[1] = temp[1].replace("Path=", "SameSite=Lax; Path=")
            self.response.headers._items[index] = tuple(temp)
```